# How to display the headers are not the left, and put them on the bar top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqchart

Good day dear colleagues. 
The problem is that the names of each bar are not where you need. The bar is located on the right and left of its name. But I need that title was above each bar, rather than his left. How this can be done, I am sure that this is not as difficult as it seem^
Here is my code:

```
$('header').jqChart({
                title: { text: title],
                    fillStyle: '#85b1de'
                },
                legend: { visible: false },
                border: { visible: false },
                axes: [
                    {
                        strokeStyle: 'transparent',
                        visible: false,
                        majorGridLines: { visible: false },
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        location: 'bottom',
                        majorTickMarks: { visible: false },
                        labels: {
                            visible : false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        strokeStyle: 'black',
                        visible: false,
                        majorGridLines: { visible: false },
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        location: 'left',
                        majorTickMarks: { visible: false },
                        labels: {
                            visible : true,
                            fillStyle: '#85b1de',
                            font: '16px sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                animation: { duration: 0.5 },
                series: [
                    {
                        pointWidth: 0.5,
                        type: 'bar',
                        fillStyles: color,
                        data: [
                            [label[0], data['a']],
                            [label[1], data['b']],
                            [label[2], data['c']],
                            [label[3], data['d']]
                        ],
                        labels: {
                            stringFormat: ' %s %%',
                            valueType: 'dataValue',
                            font: '14px sans-serif',
                            fillStyle: 'white'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
```

[image: As the image:]

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there is some CSS defining things (and not included in your code) :)

I would check it for:
- display:inline (and remove it, or change it to block),
- width of parent container can be set to "too low",...

Can we see the whole thing (html+css+js) / fiddle / ...